# How to Use casperjs in PARSE Cloud

Tags: parse-platform, phantomjs, casperjs

Hi am developing an website which need to use casperjs for crawling. Am using Parse hosting. So How can i run my .JS files using casper in PARSE?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't run arbitrary executables on in the parse cloud, so it is not possible to use CasperJS as a service on parse, because it depends on PhantomJS.